# how to use obfuscated c# executive code in create setup file?

Tags: c#, installation, obfuscation, installshield, dotfuscator

I obfuscate c# executive code using dotfuscator software, and then I created a setup file using installshield.
the problem is installshield doesn't use obfuscated file for creating setup file .
Work that installshield To build the setup file this is :
Re-compile the code, And again makes a new executable code, The new executable code is not obfuscated, This file is used to build setup file.

Comment: InstallShield does not recompile your code when creating the setup. InstallShield knows nothing about the compiler, the location of your source code, or your project. InstallShield packages the files you tell it to package and creates an installation for them.

Comment: I introduced The executable code was obfuscated to installshield, but after making setup file by installshield, and install it in the end user's pc my software can be decompile

Comment: Then you're giving InstallShield a copy of the executable before it's obfuscated. Once again, *InstallShield packages **the files you tell it to package** and creates an installation for them.* If the *executable code was obfuscated to InstallShield*, then InstallShield would be installing the obfuscated executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure I understand your question, but it sounds like you're saying you:

1. Built your code
2. Ran Dotfuscator against your app

...and that worked. But then you:

3. Configured InstallShield to package your app
4. Built the installer
5. The app in the installer is unobfuscated

Is that correct?

My guess is that in step #3, you have InstallShield pointing to the outputs from the basic build (step #1) and that you actually need to point it at the output from the Dotfuscator build (step #2). Dotfuscator typically puts its outputs into a `Dotfuscated` subdirectory, so you probably need to configure InstallShield to get its inputs from that directory, or configure Dotfuscator to overwrite the original outputs (from step #1).

Assuming you are using Dotfuscator Community Edition, you can configure Dotfuscator's build output location on the **Properties** page on the **Build Settings** tab.

Note that Dotfuscator Professional Edition has more options for how to do this integration, and full customer support. If you have Pro or are interested in it, please [contact us](https://www.preemptive.com/contact/contactus) for further help!

(Full disclosure: I work for PreEmptive Solutions.)